# Star rating using MVC5

Tags: rating-system

How to implement star rating using Mvc5?

I found a code in this link http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2828/developing-a-star-rating-in-aspnet-mvc and I did database and I added a Controller and two partial view.
here is the partial view that gave me the problem.

```
@model string


@{
    Single m_Average = 0;

    Single m_totalNumberOfVotes = 0;
    Single m_totalVoteCount = 0;
    Single m_currentVotesCount = 0;
    Single m_inPercent = 0;
    var thisVote = string.Empty;

    if (Model.Length > 0)
    {
        // calculate total votes now
        string[] votes = Model.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < votes.Length; i++)
        {
            m_currentVotesCount = Int16.Parse(votes[i]);
            m_totalNumberOfVotes = m_totalNumberOfVotes + m_currentVotesCount;
            m_totalVoteCount = m_totalVoteCount + (m_currentVotesCount * (i + 1));
        }

        m_Average = m_totalVoteCount / m_totalNumberOfVotes;
        m_inPercent = (m_Average * 100) / 5;

        thisVote = "<span style=\"display: block; width: 65px; height: 13px; background: url(/images/starRating.png) 0 0;\">" +
            "<span style=\"display: block; width: " + m_inPercent + "%; height: 13px; background: url(/images/starRating.png) 0 -13px;\"></span> " +
            "</span>" +
            "<span class=\"smallText\">Overall ratings: <span itemprop=\"ratingCount\">" + m_totalNumberOfVotes + "</span> | Rating: <span itemprop=\"ratingValue\">" + m_Average.ToString("##.##") + "</span> out of 5 </span>  ";
    }
}
<div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
    <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1">
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="@m_Average.ToString("##.##") %>" />
    @Html.Raw(thisVote)
</div>
```

when I run my application I get this error: INPUT STRING IS NOT IN A CORRECT FORMAT...

Answer (score 0):

The name says it all "INPUT STRING IS NOT IN THE CORRECT FORMAT". Where you you have input strings? on the Parse() methods.

Check the contents of your vote[] array. I am pretty sure one of those values is cannot be parsed numerically.